# Issue with automatically generating Icon Link tags in Next.js 13.4.9

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I'm developing a project using Next.js version 13.4.9 and have encountered an issue with dynamically generating  tags for icons. While my setup is successful in creating meta tags and alternate language links, it falls short in handling icon links.

Implementation Overview:

A generateMetadata function returns an object containing various metadata, including titles, descriptions, language alternates, and icons.

It successfully generates  tags for alternate language versions, structured as

```
alternates: {
canonical: '/en',
languages: {
   'en': '/en',
   // ... other languages
 },
}
```

Resulting in the expected HTML:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost:3000/en"/>
<link rel="alternate" hrefLang="en" href="http://localhost:3000/en"/>
<!-- ... more links for other languages -->
```

The challenge arises with the icons segment of the metadata object:

```
icons: {
    icon: '/favicon.ico',
    shortcut: '/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png',
    apple: '/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png',
    other: {
      rel: '/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png',
      url: '/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png',
    },
  }
```

However, this doesn't translate into  tags in the HTML head.

Paths and URLs appear correct, and the logic for meta tags and alternate links functions properly. I'm trying to figure out why the icons section isn't working similarly.

1. Are there specific considerations for handling icon links in Next.js
   13.4.9 that differ from meta tags and alternate language links?
2. Could there be something in my current Next.js version that affects this functionality? Any guidance or suggestions to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!